# How to login with an element in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Currently I have a functional login procedure. My users go to a specific *login* view, type their username and password, access and are redirected to a specific dashboard.

In my users controller:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect();
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect user or password.');
    }
}
```

The login view:

```
<h1>Access with your username:</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
        echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'User:'));
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password:'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

The issue came when I was asked to add some login fields directly in my main menu. So I tried adding them as an element in my header. It didn't work.

The element I'm adding in my header:

```
<div>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('user', array('action' => 'login'));
        echo $this->Form->input('username', array('placeholder' => 'User', 'label' => false));
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'label' => false));
        echo $this->Form->submit('Ingresar', array('div' => true));
        echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
</div>
```

I enter username and password and click the "login" button. It throws me the "Incorrect user or password." error message and redirects me to the view for the *login* action (without login in the user).

In there, one can successfully login without further issue, but the point was to reduce by 1 the needed clicks for the action.

What am I missing? What should I change/add/move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second html form, the model `User` is not typed as it should be

change

```
echo $this->Form->create('user', array('action' => 'login'));
```

To

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
```

Note the `u` changed to `U` from the model name

Comment: To explain the error you are getting : When you submit the form (the second one), the `AuthComponent` is expecting an Array as `array( 'User' => array( 'username' => '***', 'password' => '***' ))` but on your case the `AuthComponent` is receiving an array with different structure  `array( 'user' => array( 'username' => '***', 'password' => '***' ))`

Comment: That was it. So obvious in hindsight. Thank you very much!